# Thin client And Net programming

Tags: .net, thin-client

i have built a clientServer application ( C# and VS 2008 ) for a LAN network consist of several PCs . it's working fine .

now we have a network consist of a server and thin clients . i do have no idea where and how to install my client application to work correctly .

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Thin clients will connect to a server running terminal services. You will need to install your client program on that server (or servers).  It's been a long since I had to play with terminal services for this, but back then when installing software for use with thin clients you also wanted to make sure you used the option to install a program from the Add/Remove Programs control panel applet.

Answer (score 0):

Install your app on the server and test it out from the clients.  In most costs the should work correctly.

If you're using Terminal Server then be sure to install the app using the Terminal Server Install Application on Terminal Server tool to make sure any reg entries etc are set-up correctly for a multi user machine.  For earlier versions of Windows the preferred install route was via Add or Remove Programs.

Comment: earlier versions of Windows includes XP ?

Comment: I'm talking server OS here.  You install the software on the terminal server and it's then available to your thin clients on their terminal desktop.  XP does support Remote Desktop but it's a single user only scenario.

Comment: ops , you mean there is no way to use a XP OS as a server for thin clients ? , what if there were just 3 clients and all they do is to show videos from server ?

Comment: Your comments seem to be contradicting what you've put in the question a little.  You say these are thin clients therefore I've assumed that you're making terminal server connections to the server. XP cannot act as a terminal server for multiple clients.  It can however serve content to a limited number of client PCs in a workgroup if you're just using it like a file server i.e. your clients are just reading videos from the XP box but their the terminal server is another machine entirely.